# Generate image of GraphViz graph given dot text c++

Tags: c++, graphviz, dot

I have a string in a C++ Qt application (on Ubuntu) which contains valid GraphViz/dot graph syntax. I want to generate an image file/object from this text, similar to the images that various online tools (like this one: http://www.webgraphviz.com/) spit out. Maybe I'm using wrong search terms, but I can't seem to find relevant help with this.

What I basically want is something like this:

```
generate_dot_graph_image(std::string dot_text, std::string image_file_path)
```

**Additional details:** I have a Dijkstra solver whose solution (basically the original graph after removing non-used edges) I want to visualize inside my application. The solver already includes an option to convert the solution to a string that can be parsed as a dot graph using a utility such as the one I linked above. But what I want is to be able to do this from inside C++.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Are you looking to invoke graphviz from a console app? Which os? From wxWidgets, QT, MFC and display in the application?

Comment: I'm working on a QT application in Linux (ubuntu). I have a solution from a DIjkstra solver as a dot graph (text string) that I want to visualize inside my application. For this I need to convert it to an image.

Comment: Added additional details to the original question.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164156/WebControls/) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to do exactly what I wanted using the GraphViz libraries. You can install them on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install graphviz-lib` and `sudo apt-get install libgraphviz-dev`. Once that's done:

```
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>

bool DotGraphGenerator::saveImage()
{
  std::string o_arg = std::string("-o") + "/path/to/image_file.png";
  char* args[] = {const_cast<char*>("dot"), const_cast<char*>("Tpng"), const_cast<char*>("-Gsize=8,4!"), const_cast<char*>("-Gdpi=100"),
  const_cast<char*>(DOT_TEXT_FILE.c_str()),  //DOT_TEXT_FILE is the file path in which the graph is saved as valid DOT syntax
  const_cast<char*>(o_arg.c_str()) };

  const int argc = sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]);
  Agraph_t *g, *prev = NULL;
  GVC_t *gvc;

  gvc = gvContext();
  gvParseArgs(gvc, argc, args);

  while ((g = gvNextInputGraph(gvc)))
  {
    if (prev)
    {
      gvFreeLayout(gvc, prev);
      agclose(prev);
    }
    gvLayoutJobs(gvc, g);
    gvRenderJobs(gvc, g);
    prev = g;
  }

  return !gvFreeContext(gvc);
}
```

gvc is a C library, and the functions take non-const C strings as arguments, hence the const_casts in the beginning. You can also edit the image size by altering the `-Gsize=8,4` and `-Gdpi=100` args. With the current configuration you'll get an 8*100 x 4*100 = 800x400 image file. Anyway, these arguments are the same as you would apply when running the `dot` command from bash.

Other than that, this code is basically copied from one of the examples in the graphViz as a library manual: http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I found a way, I used the following function and it works:

```
bool saveImageGV(std::string file_path){
    GVC_t *gvc;
    Agraph_t *g;
    FILE *fp;
    gvc = gvContext();
    fp = fopen((file_path+".dot").c_str(), "r");
    g = agread(fp, 0);
    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRender(gvc, g, "png", fopen((file_path+".png").c_str(), "w"));
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    agclose(g);
    return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```